# Shell script to move files between two dirs

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have multiple folders which contain subfolders like JAN/ Jan/ FEB/ Feb/ MAR/ Mar/ and so on. I need to move all files from JAN/* to Jan/ , FEB/* to Feb/ and so on. How do I achieve this with a shell script?

**Edit**
Thanks to @Costas for pointing me in the right direction. His solution will work with Bash 4 and up. Since I had v3 I ended up using this.

```
for DIR in [A-Z][A-Z]*/
do
    NEWDIR=`echo "$(echo "$DIR" | sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g')"`
    mv $DIR/* $NEWDIR
done
```

sed script taken from [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/7598/convert-a-string-to-title-case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For modern `bash` (which supports case change):

```
for dir in [A-Z][a-z]*/
do
    mv -t "$dir" ${dir^^}/*
done
```

In unsupported versions you free to use `tr`|`sed`|… conversion instead.

Comment: In my (UK) locale the pattern match `[A-Z][a-z]*/` is case insensitive (i.e. it's matching `JAN` and `Jan`)

Comment: @roaima Is `[[:upper:]]` case insensitive too?

Comment: Good catch. That one works as we'd expect

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 4):

Using the Perl-based `rename` utility that comes as standard on Debian, but is known as `prename` on some other systems, you can do it with one command

```
( LC_ALL=C; prename -v 's!^([A-Z])([A-Z]{2}/)!$1\L$2!' [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/* )
```

This forces the `C` locale, which ensures that filename matching is case sensitive, allowing the file pattern `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]` to pick up only months with entirely capital letters. The substitution swaps three capital letters for a capital letter followed by two lowercase letters.

If you prefer you can swap the filename pattern `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/*` for an explicit list of all twelve months: `{JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC}/*`

Comment: `([A-Z]{2}/)` can be substituted by `([^/]*)`

Comment: @Costas, yes, agreed. Actually, the whole first part could be reduced to `^(.)(../)` by relying on the set of filenames to be correct, but I decided to spell it out explicitly.

Comment: `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/*` => `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/?*` to avoid folder(s) renaming.